# How to exclude adding empty item to localStorage

Tags: javascript

I have a todo List on my website and I want to save all tasks that users write.
But when users click on the "Add" button without entering a task, an empty line is stored in LocalStorage. What condition do I need to add to my code to exclude adding empty lines to LocalStorage.
Right now my code for adding items looks like this:

```
 btn.onclick = function(){
        let userData = input.value;
        let getLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem("New Todo");
         if(getLocalStorage == null){
             listArr = [];
         } else{
             listArr = JSON.parse(getLocalStorage);
         }
         listArr.push(userData);
         localStorage.setItem("New Todo", JSON.stringify(listArr));
    };
```

Comment: You should check the `input.value` if it is falsy then return from the function.

Comment: `if(userData != "")`

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is check whether your input is empty or not.
Something like:

```
// This will check if the value is not null or undefined
// and the input length is greater than 0
if (input.value && input.value.length > 0) {
  // your logic here
}
```

You could trim the whitespaces as well, and check again wheter the length of the input is grater than 0 or not. This way, if someone just enters a bunch of spaces, it won't be added to your LS.

Answer (score 1):

basically bail out at the beginning of the function if the value is empty or contains spaces only

```js
 btn.onclick = function(){
         if (!input.value || !input.value.trim()) {
          return
        }
        let userData = input.value;
        let getLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem("New Todo");
         if(getLocalStorage == null){
             listArr = [];
         } else{
             listArr = JSON.parse(getLocalStorage);
         }
         listArr.push(userData);
         localStorage.setItem("New Todo", JSON.stringify(listArr));
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Just before set item in localStorage check listArr wasn't empty:

```
if(listArr.length > 0){
  localStorage.setItem("New Todo", JSON.stringify(listArr));
}
```